# Latest Kendo Web (2014.1.318) model.set method not working

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik

Seems like there's a bug in the latest version of Kendo Web.

I'm using the select event of a drop down list in a custom popup grid editor to set the value of other fields in the model. The code for the select evet looks like:

```
function select(e) {
  var data = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
  var win = this.element.closest("[data-role=window]");
  var uid = win.data("uid");
  var model = grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.getByUid(uid);
  model.set('field', data.value);
}
```

I can confirm that the dataItem of the selected drop down item is correctly returned, as is the model of the row being edited.

No errors are generated, but the model is not updated. The same code works with version 2013.3.1316.

I don't know if anyone from Telerik looks on these forums?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see the problem is in `data.value`. Did you check that it contains the desired value?

I did this:

```
    select : function (e) {
        var data = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
        var win = this.element.closest("[data-role=window]");
        var uid = win.data("uid");
        var model = grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.getByUid(uid);
        model.set('field', data);
    }
```

trying to reproduce your code and works fine.

Check the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/XNcmt/33/ where I copy the value that you select for `City` column into `City2` column.

Comment: Hi. This is really strange. I've edited your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XNcmt/45/) so that it's more in line with what I'm doing, and it works perfectly. In my implementation, it's simply not working: I've output the `data` object to the console and it's correct. I've tried outputting the `model` to the console immediately after calling `model.set` and the field is not updated. Like I say -- the exact same code is working perfectly with the last 2013 release.

Comment: I've just looked into this some more, and I've tracked down the problem, but don't know why it's happening. I'm using `model.set` to update several fields. Most of them are updated correctly, but some aren't. Those that aren't updated are called `elr`, `start_val` and `end_val`. The latter two have custom validation which checks that their values are in a certain range. If I remove the validation everything is fine. I've updated the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XNcmt/49/) to demonstrate the problem.